# What is the use/purpose of the NOLOCK hint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In `SELECT * FROM tablename  (NOLOCK)`,

Why we use NOLOCK option, how worth this in sql server? is it working during transaction.

the NOLOCK option using in select statement only or during update statement.

Comment: is google broken? NOLOCK takes and honors no locks. Whether you should be doing so is unclear, but unlikely.

Comment: Check http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/

Comment: `nolock` is used to work around SQL Server's outdated locking behavior. Nowadays using `read committed snapshot` isolation level is the recommended approach to avoid writers blocking readers

Answer (score 3):

The NOLOCK is to be used with SELECTs only. SQL Server will lock the resource on UPDATE/INSERT regardless of any setting you can possibly set.

NOLOCK instructs the engine to not try setting a shared lock on a row before reading it. This way, if the row is already being exclusively locked by some other update transaction, it won't have to wait until the exclusive lock is released.

It will, however, read non-committed data, so there is a possibility of getting wrong results from queries.

I would recommend against using it. Better to use READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT isolation if there's a problem with blocking.

Answer (score 1):

It is to be used with SELECT only on tables that are not changing (data warehouses come to my mind). If a table updates, it may get rows double if an index split happens during the read. It is great for read only large data warehouses (outside the obviouis data load) because the locks on a 10 billion row select query take serious ressources - anything else is reckless.

Comment: Good answer also I would like to add another thing that query hints like `WITH (NOLOCK)` is equilant to setting `Transaction Isolation level to READUNCOMMIITED` , the only difference is transaction isolation level will have NOLOCK on any statements in that transaction, using query hints we can limit this nolocking behaviour to one or two tables in a transaction.